# How to draw a p5.js circle over an HTML image

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I am loading an image into my web app using standard JS and HTML  It just just a simple map and my goal is to draw on it using p5.js.

```html
<div id="map">
    <img src="Assets/MENA.jpg" class="image" width="1500" height="750">
</div>
```

```js
function conflictMapMENA() {
    this.name="MENA conflict map";
    this.id="conflict-map"


    this.draw = function() {
        var map = document.createElement('img')
        map.src = 'Assets/MENA.jpg'

        gallery.selectVisual(map);

        fill(255, 0, 0);
        ellipse(30, 30, 10);
    }

}
```

Inside `this.draw = function(){}`, I am invoking p5.js library's `ellipse()` and `fill()` functions to draw a red circle. This is what it looks like:

[image]

But when I try to adjust the coordinates to move the circle over the map, the circles go under it. Is there a way for me to have these two things cooperate without me having to draw the circle in pure JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the image to be in your actual HTML? If not, you can use the `loadImage()` and `image()` functions in p5.js:

```js
let myImage;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  myImage = loadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Domestic_Cat_Demonstrating_Dilated_Slit_Pupils.jpg/220px-Domestic_Cat_Demonstrating_Dilated_Slit_Pupils.jpg");
}

function draw() {
  image(myImage, 0, 0, width, height);
  
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, 100, 100);
}
```

[image: cat with circle]

If you do need your image in your actual HTML, then you can use a combination of CSS and the `parent()` function to make the image overlap with your sketch:

```html
  <body>
    <div id="my-canvas"
         style="position:absolute;"></div>

    <img style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"
         src="path/to/image.png" />
    
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
```

```js
function setup() {
  const canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
  canvas.parent('my-canvas');
}

function draw() {
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, 100, 100);
}
```

[image: cat with circle]

Comment: What are the `width` and `height` in your `draw()` function? You're not passing any arguments.

Comment: @oo92 you probably want to read up on [using variables in p5.js](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/using-variables)

Comment: Where would I put the first JS code you've posted? How would I alter my `conflictMapMENA()` function?

Comment: @oo92 I'm not sure I understand your question. You'd put the code wherever you're normally putting your p5.js code. I personally used the [p5.js editor](https://editor.p5js.org/). You might want to read [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/welcome-to-coding) and [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/editors) for more info.

Answer (score -3):

Just checked your doubt the background is overlapping the circle because of the depth u can give the depth of the circle greater than the backgroung

Comment: Sorry but what?